# Solution $X$ for $X(X^TX)^{-1}=X(Y^TY)^{-1}$

Tags: matrix-equations

I have a square matrix $Y$ and I would like to find the solution $X$ for the following equation:
$$X(X^TX)^{-1}=X(Y^TY)^{-1}$$

In this equation, we can suppose that $Y^TY$ is invertible. We could also rewrite the equation as:
$$X\left(I-(Y^TY)^{-1}X^TX\right)=0$$
if this could be useful, at least there is no requirement that $X^TX$ is invertible in this form.

Is this a common equation or one where the solution is straightforward to write?

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, $X=Y$ will probably work!

Comment: How about using X=Y?

Comment: Probably worth a try! Indeed I am sometimes looking for a complex answer to a so simple question...

Comment: There is more than one solution; for instance, $X = QY$ for every orthonormal $Q$. So it would be better to specify if you want *a* solution, or to describe *all* solutions.

Comment: I am looking for any solution as the important matrix is $X^TX$. So the ease of computation is more my concern here. Any solution is acceptable (so $X=Y$ is good).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $X(X^T X)^{-1}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $X^T$. Using properties of pseudo-inverse we get

$(Y^TY)(X^T X)^\dagger = I$

For instance $X=Y$ or $X=\text{Cholesky}(Y^T Y)$